# How to remove the colon from cvitemwithcomment?

Tags: formatting, punctuation, moderncv

This is my code and it automatically puts a colon after the "Intern - Technology" bit, how do I override this and get rid of it?

```
\cvitemwithcomment{\normalfont{HSBC, London,} \textbf{Intern - Technology Division}}{}{\normalfont{Jun--August 2015}}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\vspace{2mm}
\end{itemize}
```

this is the class I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
```

Comment: Please share a link to the template in use.

Comment: It is also important to know which style you are using.

Comment: `\moderncvstyle{banking}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{:}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitemwithcomment}{:}{}{}{}
`

Comment: sorry this is the style i am using  \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}         
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{black}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

Comment: Please add it to the question, that will pop it on top of the main site and more users see your question.

Answer (score 1):

Without going as far as redefining `\cvitemwithcomment`, you can capture the `:` and remove it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking} 

\firstname{First}
\lastname{Lastname}

\let\oldcvitemwithcomment\cvitemwithcomment
\let\oldhintstyle\hintstyle
\renewcommand{\cvitemwithcomment}[4]{{%
  \renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[2]{\oldhintstyle{##1}}%
  \oldcvitemwithcomment{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}}

\begin{document}

\cvitemwithcomment
  {{\normalfont HSBC, London,} \textbf{Intern - Technology Division}}
  {}
  {{\normalfont Jun--August 2015}}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the original definition of `\cvitemwithcomment` where the insertion of `:` is visible in the first line:

```
\renewcommand*{\cvitemwithcomment}[4][.25em]{%
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2}: }#3}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}{\widthof{\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedleft\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

you can change this to suit your needs and adding the resulting code your preamble after loading the style of your choice.