# How to remove colon from a single cvitemwithcomment

Tags: moderncv, cv

I checked this post before - [How to remove the colon from cvitemwithcomment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319809/117939), but it involves changing what happens in the whole document, by altering the cvitemwithcomment in the preamble.

Is there anything I can do to change it in a section/subsection alone?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Jane}{Doe}
\address{1st street, 123}{1234-123}{Place}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Language skills}
\cvitemwithcomment{Portuguese}{Mother tongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Good}{I want to keep the colons here}
\cvitemwithcomment{French}{Sufficient}{in this subsection}

\subsection{Lectures}
\cvitemwithcomment[1em]{\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{It doesn't make sense to me to keep}}{\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{the colons here (2017)}}{in this part}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define your own non-colon version of `\cvitemwithcomment`, say `\cvitemwithcommentnocolon`; the [`moderncv` class](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) doesn't provide an option for easily removing this component:

```
\newcommand*{\cvitemwithcommentnocolon}[4][.25em]{%
  \savebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\hintstyle{#2} }#3}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}{\widthof{\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}}}%
  \setlength{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}{\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth-\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentmainlength}\usebox{\cvitemwithcommentmainbox}\end{minipage}%
  \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength}\raggedleft\small\itshape#4\end{minipage}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```